# Parsing JsonString in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am new in Swift ,I am getting below JsonObject as a String,and I want to get LoginStatus's value, how can I parse it

```
{
   "ID":16,
   "NameSurname":"UĞUR ACAR",
   "LoginStatus":"True"
}
```

I am trying parse in here but it gives error

```
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if currentElementName == "LoginResult" {

            var status = ""

            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(string.utf8))
                status = res.loginStatus

            } catch  {
                print("Unable to decode", error)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let nameSurname, loginStatus: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case nameSurname = "NameSurname"
        case loginStatus = "LoginStatus"
    }
}
```

---

```
    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))

    } catch  {
        print("Unable to decode", error)
    }
```

Comment: this is xml parses sure string is a jsonString ?

Comment: I can't get value of loginStatus, I got as a jsonString

Comment: @Diego res.loginStatus would have the value in this code example.